# Sorting numbers into bins

Tags: c#

I have two 2D arrays of doubles `a` and `b`. Both have two rows and different numbers of columns.

```
a [[ 1,2,3][4,5,6]]
```

The list `b` represents a number of bins of numbers and the list is a list of numbers I'm trying to sort into these bins.

I need to go through each of the numbers in `b` to look for its corresponding bin. Here's the code I have, which works perfectly but I need to optimize it. Any ideas?

```
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(1); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.GetLength(1); j++) {

                //if fragment falls in bin, add it to the new object
                if (a[0, i] <= (b[0, j] + binSize / 2) &&
                    a[0, i] > (b[0, j] - binSize / 2)) {

                    c[0, k] = a[0, i];
                    c[0, k] = b[0, j];

                    c[1, k] = a[1, i];
                    c[1, k] = b[1, j];
                    k++;

                }
                if (k >= a.GetLength(1)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should add how is `binSize` is declared, it would help us to understand your code.

Comment: What is the purpose of `c[0, k] = a[0, i];` followed by `c[0, k] = b[0, j];`? Are you sure the code is working correctly?

Comment: One optimization I would do is create a variable for binSize / 2 outside your loops and place that new variable in your if statement.  That way that calculation isn't made 2*O(n^2) times.

I would also do the same for your a.GetLength(1) and b.GetLength(1) for the same reason.

Comment: This question would have substantially better answers if you provided more context on what sorts of values the binSizes can be, whether values can 'fall between' different bins, and whether binSizes are at regular intervals

Answer (score 7):

> Here's the code I have, which works perfectly
>
> ```
> int k = 0;
> for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(1); i++) {
>     for (int j = 0; j < b.GetLength(1); j++) {
>
>         //if fragment falls in bin, add it to the new object
>         if (a[0, i] <= (b[0, j] + binSize / 2) &&
>             a[0, i] > (b[0, j] - binSize / 2)) {
>
>             c[0, k] = a[0, i];
>             c[0, k] = b[0, j];
>
>             c[1, k] = a[1, i];
>             c[1, k] = b[1, j];
>             k++;
>
>         }
>         if (k >= a.GetLength(1)) {
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

It is obviously better to extract the `binSize / 2` outside of the for loops, as `binSize` is never changed. So the repeating `binSize / 2` isn't needed. Assuming binSize is an int:

```
int halfBinSize = binSize / 2;
```

Also `a.GetLength(1)` and `b.GetLength(1)` won't change, but are queried each time in the inner loop so refactor like this:

```
int lengthA = a.GetLength(1);
int lengthB = b.GetLength(1);
```

As you overwrite the values of

> ```
>             c[0, k] = a[0, i];
>             c[0, k] = b[0, j];
>
>             c[1, k] = a[1, i];
>             c[1, k] = b[1, j];
> ```

this can be reduced to

```
c[0, k] = b[0, j];
c[1, k] = b[1, j];
```

As the context isn't known let's keep the check for `k >= a.GetLength(1)`

<s>the check for `k >= a.GetLength(1)` can be removed as you are using the a[,] only to compare with b[,] the check can be removed completely</s>

but we place it to the looping condition

```
for (int j = 0; k >= lengthA && j < lengthB; j++)
```

and we should refactor a[0,i] to outside the inner loop

```
double currentA = a[0,i];
```

which results overall in

```
int halfBinSize = binSize / 2;
int lengthA = a.GetLength(1);
int lengthB = b.GetLength(1);
double currentA;

int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lengthA; i++) 
{

    currentA = a[0,i];

    for (int j = 0; k >= lengthA && j < lengthB; j++) 
    {
        //if fragment falls in bin, add it to the new object
        if (currentA  <= (b[0, j] + halfBinSize) &&
            currentA  > (b[0, j] - halfBinSize)) 
        {

            c[0, k] = b[0, j];

            c[1, k] = b[1, j];
            k++;

        }
    }
}
```